# I want to create a set from a list to which items are inserted at runtime. I am trying this way

Tags: python

I want to create a set from a list to which items are inserted at runtime. I am trying this way.

```
l=[input().split()]
s=set(l)
```

it's giving an error
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Did you want `l = input().split()` without wrapping it in an extra list?

Comment: You are creating a list of lists, but your just want a list @HarikrishnaGannu Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 3):

`input().split()` already gives you a list, you don't need to wrap it into another list

```
l=input().split()
s=set(l)
print(s)
```

The output will be

```
1 2 3 1 2 3
{'2', '3', '1'}
```

You cannot convert a list of lists into a set by casting it as a set, which is because a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) asks for an optional `iterable` argument, the elements of the set must be hashable.
Which holds true for a list, since the elements of the iterable, an `integer` is hashable, but not true for a list of lists, since the elements of the iterable, a list is not hashable

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable

> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not.

```
In [36]: set([1,2,3])                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[36]: {1, 2, 3}

In [37]: set([[1,2,3]])                                                                                                                                                                                                      

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```